# Analysis to be carried out in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database which captures everyday every column data as binary 0 or 1 in a SQL database. Now I want to calculate what is the avg no. of days a user takes to complete that column. How can I run the query for that?

Please note timeline for every user is different and I want data to be in 3 days slab (for example 1-3,4-6 so on and so forth).

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Please provide an example of what your data looks like, what you expect the output to look like, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: (1) I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are actually using.  (2) Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @SandPiper I am using SQL Server

Comment: @GordonLinoff I can provide you the data its confidential but you assume it like below


u_id        is_flag_set       is_name_set
1                 0                           1
2                 1                           0

Comment: You don't need to provide the actual confidential data, just a set of representative example records so we can better understand what we are looking at.